# Check when the page is loaded AND opening animation has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, callback

I'm in front of a conceptual problem.
At the beginning of my site I have an `OPENING ANIMATION` (in sostitution of loader) that I want to show all, from the beginning to the end, of course. Then when the page is completely loaded I'll show the page.

Now there are 2 different situations:

- FIRST: fast internet -> page is loaded before the animation is over
- SECOND: slow internet -> the opening finish before the end of loading

What I want to achieve is to `show the entire opening` and then `IF the page is loaded close the opening/loader`, OR `IF the page is not loaded wait until the end of the loading to close the opening/loader`.

I thought to use `$(windows).load("close loader")` but in case of the loading is fast the loader will be closed before the end of animation.

### WHAT I TRIED

```
$(window).load(function(){
        if( done ){
            console.log("bar done");
            $("#openingLoader").addClass("done");
        }
        done = true;
    });
```

AND IN THE CALLBACK OF OPENING ANIMATION

```
if( done ){
        console.log("opening done");
        $("#openingLoader").addClass("done");
        }
done = true;
```

But I don't think is a good way to solve that.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please keep in mind you visitors may get anoyed if they have to go through the whole animation everytime they visit the page. You should provide a way to "skip" (when pageload is done) the animation.

Comment: yup, i know that but it's a short animation :), more or less 3/4 secs

Answer (score 3):

You clearly have two conditions in your question, but only one condition for each of your tried solutions.

Set a callback to a page load function when either the animation finishes or the page loads. The page load function needs to check if both the conditions are fulfilled, and if so - open the page.

Pseudo code:

```
animationFinishedCallback = function(){
  animationFinished = true;
  tryPageOpen();
}
pageLoadedCallback = function(){
  pageLoaded = true;
  tryPageOpen();
}

function tryPageOpen() {
  if (animationFinished && pageLoaded) {
     openPage();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I got the solution, and I feel soo stupid because I didn't think about that :O Was so simple! Btw, I'll try for sure. Thanks Shomz

Comment: It happens to everyone, don't worry. You're welcome!